# BufferedWriter in Android performance

Tags: java, android, file-io, bufferedwriter

I'm writing data to a file (received via BLE) in Android.

Is there a performance difference between multiple calls to the BufferedWriter such as:

```
_writer.write(String.valueOf(sampleNumber));
_writer.write(",");
_writer.write(String.valueOf(characteristic.getIntValue(formatU8, 0)));
_writer.write(",");
_writer.write(String.valueOf(characteristic.getIntValue(formatU8, 1)));
_writer.write(",");
```

versus building a String and then calling BufferedWriter once per data item received.

```
str1 = String.valueOf(_savedSampleCount) + "," + String.valueOf(characteristic.getIntValue(formatU8, 0)) + ","   + String.valueOf(characteristic.getIntValue(formatU8, 1)) + ",";
```

Or should I use StringBuilder instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write directly to the BufferedWriter, as your posted code does.

> buffering characters so as to provide for the efficient writing of **single characters**, arrays, and strings.

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) (emphasis mine)